# Is an average function integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm thinking about the following question:

If $u\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, is $f(x)=\int_{|y-x|<R}|u(x)-u(y)|^pdy$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $R>0$ is a fixed numbers?

It's clear that if $u$ has compact support then it's true, but is it true for general $L^p$ functions, which have certain decay? I tried to approximate $u$ by $C_c^\infty$ functions but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try to approximate by step functions?

Comment: I got something like $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}fdx\leq 2\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\epsilon dx+\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{|y-x|<R}|u_k(x)-u_k(y)|^p dydx$ and hence blow up... Or is it fixable?